# If $u_n-\sum_{k=1}^m c_ku_{n-k}$ converges, what conditions on the $c_k$ imply that $u_n$ converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations

This is a generalization of
[For $\alpha \in ]-1, 1[$, how to show that sequence $(u_{n + 1} - \alpha u_n)$ converges implies $(u_n)$ converges?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2935922/for-alpha-in-1-1-how-to-show-that-sequence-u-n-1-alpha-u-n-c)

If
$u_n-\sum_{k=1}^m c_ku_{n-k}$
converges,
what conditions on the
$c_k$
imply that
$u_n$ converges?

Based on the source problem,
my conjecture is that,
if
$f(x) 
=x^m-\sum_{k=1}^m c_kx^{m-k}$,
then a sufficient condition 
is that the roots
of $f(x)$,
$(x_k)_{k=1}^m$
are all simple and
satisfy
$|x_k| < 1$.

I think a proof
could be constructed by
writing 
$d_n =u_n-\sum_{k=1}^m c_ku_{n-k}$,
getting the expansion of
$u_n$ in terms of
the $x_k$
and the initial $u_j$,
and then using
$\lim_{n \to \infty} d_n $
exists and
$|x_k|^n \to 0$
for all $k$.

Another way might be
to get the generating function
for $u_n$ in terms of
$f(x)$.

However,
I have other things to do,
and this looks like
it would take a while,
so I'll leave it like this.